# How to translate jQuery .live() to .on() with events bound to this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of converting code from the deprecated `.live()` API to `.on()` (see the [jQuery 1.7 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/))

I have live events attached to `this` in multiple custom jQuery plugins, e.g.

```
this.live('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

the [jQuery .live() doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has some guidance on how to migrate to `.on()` as follows:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

however, this doesn't work:

```
$(document).on('click', this, function() {
    ...
});
```

so... how do I make live events bound to `this` work with the new `on()` API?

Comment: `bind`, `delegate`, and `live` are not deprecated AFAIK, unless you've found an official notice stating that they are, in which case: please cite your source.

Comment: The notice about live being deprecated is right in the jQuery docs that akavlie linked to.

Comment: zzzzBov, it states clearly in [this blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/), as well as the doc for [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) that it's deprecated. `.bind()` & `.delegate()` otoh are considered to be *superseded* but not *deprecated* apparently. Seems that they took the more firm stance on `.live()` due to the downsides noted in the doc.

Comment: @AnthonyJack, @akavlie, I apologize for the mistake, I hadn't noticed the change to the `live` docs. I think it ought to be in big bold print at the top to alert developers, rather than tucked under the function signatures discreetly.

Comment: @zzzzBov No biggie, yeah I agree it should be highlighted more.  I just happened to know that change was coming soon so looked for it a little more closely in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$(document).on('click', this.selector, handler);
```

A jQuery object has a `selector` property that represents the selector used to create that object.

Note that the selector is modified with traversal methods, so I would assume that your plugin is generally used upon initial DOM selection.

---

To avoid using an internal property, you could simply change the API of your plugin to require a selector to be passed explicitly.

Comment: Bingo, that did it!

Someone ought to add this to the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 3):

The .selector property is undocumented and probably will be removed when .live() is removed. What did this code look like when you were using .live()? How are these plugins used?

Comment: As an example, I have a plugin that adds some functionality to scrollable lists -- show arrow graphics if they grow past a certain length & add mousewheel scrolling and such. I used `this.live()` here as these can be added to/replaced in the DOM after the page loads. It's the same use case as `.live()` anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

As of jQuery 1.7, the [`on`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on) function is used to replace the existing separate methods of binding events:

- [`bind`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/bind)
- [`delegate`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)
- [`live`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/live)

[`one`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/one) is a special case, and you should continue to use it as is.

The existing events continue to exist, and are simply aliases of `on`. <del>There is no official report to suggest that they will be removed, so you'd be safe to continue to use them if you understand them better.</del> `live` and `die` have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 as mentioned in [a blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/) and on the [`live` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live).

The `on` event has multiple formats, but the function signature is as follows:

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler )
```

#### Bind:

```
$(selector).bind(events, data, handler);
$(selector).on(events, null, data, handler);
```

[Source:](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
  return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
}
```

#### Delegate:

```
$(selector).delegate(subselector, events, data, handler);
$(selector).on(events, subselector, data, handler);
```

[Source:](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)

```
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
  return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
}
```

#### Live:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);
```

[Source:](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
  jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
  return this;
}
```

<sub>Note that `this.context` was set using `this.context = document;` as specified at `$(document).on(...)`.</sub>

Comment: This is a good overview of transitioning to the `.on()` API in general... but it doesn't address my question.

Comment: @akavlie, "The existing events continue to exist, and are simply aliases of `on`. There is no official report to suggest that they will be removed, so you'd be safe to continue to use them if you understand them better." how does that not address your question?

Comment: There is actually an official report suggesting that they will be removed:

(1) "deprecated" means the feature is no longer approved, and almost always implied future removal. -- 
(2) The jQuery blog suggests [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/) that the goal is removal of the deprecated features; [more recently](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/22/call-for-jquery-1-8-ideas/) removal was addressed again, stating that it would not happen until 2.0.

Comment: @akavlie, that's good to know, linking to a source on jQuery that explicitly says "deprecated" is what I needed to be convinced. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).on(events, data, handler)
```

Still works fine. You could still use that. Check out the **[`.on` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: This is the equivalent to `$(selector).bind()`, not `$(selector).live()`.