# How to only reference one element when using .live("click" with elements within each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<div id="outerrt">
  <div id="rt" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <span id="rt2">content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I use the following:

```
$("#outerrt *").live("click", function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

What it would give me when I click on the `content` text is three alert windows, in the following order:

`rt2`

`rt`

`outerrt`

What I actually want it to give me is only one id: `rt2`. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @SnakeEyes But does `on` automatically accept newly created elements of the same circumstances?

Comment: Then use `delegate` as mentioned in below answers from different users. See @undefined answer

Comment: yes, events will bubble up the DOM tree until it reaches #outerrt. `live`, `delegate` and `on` will all trigger. `delegate` and `on` then check if the event started on something matching their more specific selector to decide whether to call the event handler. Newly created elements lower in the hierarchy still trigger at the #outerrt level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `target` property of the `event` object.

```
$(document).on("click", '#outerrt', function(event) {
      alert(event.target.id);
      // $(event.target).attr('id')
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't bind on document if you have a much closer element you can bind to

Comment: @agreco It seems that _event delegation_ is not necessary here. How do you know that `outerrt` is a static element?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be 100% jQuery. Can you make it like that?

Comment: the OP binded `live` on #outerrt, so I think we can assume that this element is static, even if its contents are not.

Comment: @ronalchn: The `live` method always binds the event at document level, so it's not certain that any element in the selector exists at that time.

Comment: @think123 jQuery is JavaScript, what do you mean by 100% jQuery? I have updated the code.

Comment: yep that's what i mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$("#rt2").live("click", function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: sorry it isn't, as the content for `rt` is constantly changing, and may not even contain the `rt2` element.

Comment: I think what you can do I think is to apply the live click event to **$("rt .your_added_obj")** and to make sure to add the class **"your_added_obj"** to the object you will add.

Comment: The OP says it needs to work with newly created objects, in which case binding directly to the object isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#outerrt').on( 'click', '#rt', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

edit: $(this) works just as well as $(e.target)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would only give you the first two alerts, as the `#outerrt *` selector doesn't match the element with `id="outerrt"`.

To stop the event from bubbling, use the `stopPropagation` method:

```
$("#outerrt *").live("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

In newer versions of jQuery the `live` and `delegate` methods are deprecated, and they have crammed all that functionality into the `on` method, so the equivalent code would be:

```
$("body").on("click", "#outerrt *", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

However, you should put the delegate as close as possible to the elements where you want to catch the event, i.e. on the element where you will be loading the content. Example:

```
$("#outerrt").on("click", "*", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either bind it directly on #rt2, or use `delegate` or `on` instead (depending on your jQuery version).

- delegate(): http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ (use for jQuery < 1.7)
- on(): http://api.jquery.com/on/ (use for jQuery 1.7+)

Using `delegate`, you can pass a more specific selector:

```
$("#outerrt *").delegate("span","click", function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Similarly with `on`:

```
$("#outerrt").on("click", "#rt2", function(event){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

In either case the more specific selector (`span` or `#rt2`) means that it only triggers if the click occurs on something matching that selector.

Comment: When you say `depending on your jQuery version`, I've got the latest (1.8.0). Can you tell me what to use for this specific version? Thanks.

Comment: Use `on`. As of jQuery 1.7, `on` supersedes `delegate`. This means `delegate` is likely to be deprecated and removed in the future.

Comment: @think123 .live() is deprecated, you should use .on(). More information found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on