# jquery append and on methods

Tags: jquery, html

I have this page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="elem"></div>
<button id="addElem">Add Element</button>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //add element to elem div
        $("#addElem").click(function () {
            $("#elem").append('<a id="test" href="#">this is a test</a><br />');
        });

        //remove added elements on click event
        $("#test").on("click", function(){
            alert(12);
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What it is doing, is adding a link and I would like to be able to click on the added link and display an alert message but the alert is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.delegate() vs .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on) You aren't using the correct syntax for delegated events with .on. Your current usage is identical to using `.click(function(){...`

Comment: Isn't the problem here that jquery is running *before* the element with #test is even available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to...

```
$("#elem").on("click", "#test", function(){
        alert(12);
});
```

The jQuery [blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) has a great explanation for this.

`$(elements).on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler );`

> When a selector is provided, .on() is similar to .delegate() in that it attaches a >delegated event handler, filtered by the selector. When the selector is omitted or null >the call is like .bind(). There is one ambiguous case: If the data argument is a string, >you must provide either a selector string or null so that the data isn’t mistaken as a >selector. Pass an object for data and you’ll never have to worry about special cases.

Comment: that's not correct js syntax i believe. also, could you give an explanation as to why it fixes it?

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin Explanation added, was working on the edit when your comment came in.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an anchor for the event.  Since you have no other wrapper, add the document to that:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    alert(12);
});
```

NOTE: This will ONLY work on the first click as you would be adding multiple ID's that would be duplicates.

Better way:

```
$("#addElem").click(function () {
    $("#elem").append('<a class="test" href="#">this is a test</a><br />');
});
$(document).on("click", ".test", function(){
    alert(12);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the function to the created element at the time you create it:

```
$("#elem").append($('<a>', {
  id: "test.
  href: "#",
  text: "this is a test",
  click: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(12);
  })
).append($("<br>"));
```