# Refreshing the Div not working when link is inside

Tags: jquery

What I try to accomplish is refreshing the data inside a DIV without reload entire page, but it is not working as expected.

I have this Jquery code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Col1').on('click', function() {
    var url = 'PurchaseRequestList.asp?order2=PRID';        
    $('#div1-wrapper').load(url + ' #div1'); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Below is the HTML codes

```
<div id="div1-wrapper">
    <div id="div1" style="border:solid 1px red; width: 100%;"> 
        <table width="90%" align="center" class="RowDetail">
            <tr>
                <td><a id="Col1">Column1</a></td>
                <td>Column2</td>
                <td>Column3</td>
                <td>Column4</td>
            </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I moved the link (below) outside of the DIV, it will work. But if the link below is inside of the DIV that being refresh with data, it only work for the 1st click, and stop working after that.

```
<a id="Col1">Column1</a>
```

Please help with a sample code if possible.

Comment: you have to delegate event to **closest static container** : `$('#div1-wrapper').on('click','#Col1', function() {...});`

Comment: Please reference answers here, a lot more documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply change:

```
$('#Col1').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#Col1', function(e) {
```

---

This is the old argument of direct vs delegated events.  By using delegated events, you can ensure dynamically added elements maintain that event chain.  In newer versions, such as seen in your example (using .on), you can delegate `.on` to either *a parent* of the element you want to target, or the document itself. Many feel targeting the `document` is bad practice as they claim `overhead` issues. Personally, I've been using this method since .on was introduced, have used it on at least 3 programs that see thousands of daily visitors and haven't had one complaint. I say, unless you're making a JS only video game, stick with `$(document)` as it it's easier to keep up with and allows you to continually "[chain](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)" delegated events as needed without ever recalling `$(document)`

---

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- http://api.jquery.com/live/

---

## Example

Comment: `live('click', function()` for older versions of jQuery

Comment: @A.Wolff I would assume the down vote was because it would be better to bind to the `#div1-wrapper` than the document.

Comment: @BlakePlumb correct, that's why downvoter could have explain it, at least IMHO. Now, i appreciate SpYk3HH edit

Comment: @A.Wolff *"better"* is a matter of argument if you'll see my update

Comment: @milacay That's what i'm here for :) ... I've got YEARS experience with JS and jQuery, so that one was purty ez. Ask anymore anytime and welcome so SO!

Comment: When I was voting down, there were nothing in the answer but first two code snippets making the same things. Reset my vote now.