# delegate() vs on() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I know the difference between [delegate() and on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on), but I have a doubt that [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) is very popular and faster than [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) then why jquery is not removing the `delegate()` from its library.

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) has drawbacks then it is removed from `jQuery-1.9 version`.
Also if we see the [performance between on() and delegate()](http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-delegation/85) then `on()` is much faster than `delegate()`.

Then any reason to keep delegate() in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what a member of the jQuery team wrote [in regard to this issue](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/delegate-vs-on) in 2013:

> "We haven't deprecated `.bind` or `.delegate`, nor have we indicated we're
>   removing them at any point.
>
> They're each only one line in the source so size reduction isn't much of a reason to remove them.
>
> We deprecated `.live` because it has lots of confusing issues that we can't fix."

Basically, while `delegate()` has been superseded by `on()`, there are no future plans to deprecate `delegate()` due to the fact it takes up very little space (and doesn't cause any problems).

Comment: "It takes up very little space" see the `live()` on http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js I don't think it also takes too much space then delegate()

Comment: @RohanKumar True, but as mentioned live() was removed for other reasons

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

It is just legacy code. Don't use it.

Comment: Agreed, and saw the code `delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) { return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );},` in `jquery 1.9`, so this should be removed from jquery if their is no difference, not? Same question may raise for `bind()`.

Comment: "Should be removed" is a somewhat subjective question of backwards-compatibility vs streamlining of the API.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more to do with whether they want to break the users who has used it.... in terms of delegated handlers I don't see any performance diff between them...

So as advised new code should use .on() not .delegate

Comment: So, somehow you agreed with removing delegate() from jquery, and you can check the performance on http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-delegation/85

Comment: @RohanKumar the performance difference is because `.on()` has to do some conditional checks to see what kind of event has to be registered

Answer (score 2):

`on` is meant to replace `delegate`. Probably the jquery authors might keep it sometime long to make it more backward compatible. Many old plugins still use those methods. probably that might be the reason to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform both event binding and delegation with the help of `on()` method. Just the syntax differs.

Just visit this link:

http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

They have beautifully explained with examples