# DOM property to indicate whether an element was updated

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using '**contenteditable=true**' to enable edits on certain table cells. Now I want to know which of the editable elements on the page have actually been edited by the user, so that I can process the changes.

Although I could probably use event-listeners for this purpose, this approach will be tedious in my case. The page is dynamically generated and it has a variable number of editable elements. I want to avoid having to dynamically add event-listeners for every editable element.

I want to know if the DOM already has a property/flag to indicate whether an element has been updated. If so, I'd like to have a solution along these lines:

```
var element_123 = document.getElementById("element_id_123");
 var was_edited = element_123.was_edited;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to listen to the `keyup` and `keydown` events. I couldn't figure out another way.

Comment: @Spingolini I'm trying to avoid having to write low-level listener code. My question is whether the DOM already keeps track of whether an element was modified or not. I don't need the DOM to tell me what change was made, only whether or not an element was changed.

Comment: use sessionStorage, set the sessionStorage and compare the string at the time of submission, this way you are using a tiny storage on the client side and not throwing event unusually when someone typing.

Comment: @Adrian you did not understand my question

Comment: You need to do this by yourself. There's no `was_edited`-like attribute. Take a look at this article, it might solve your problem: https://coderwall.com/p/lxl3zw

Comment: @Spingolini Thanks, that was helpful. I was hoping that DOM would have a generic solution for this though.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find anything beyond that ...

Comment: Does it really make a difference if you write a listener that you attach dynamically or a function that is called by HTML? Work is around the same.

Comment: @Sens if I do it myself via event listeners, then I'd also need to come up with a naming scheme, so that each editable element gets a unique id. And then I'd need to store the edited element's id in sessionStorage (or somewhere else) for tracking  the modified elements. It's definitely feasible, but a DOM-level flag for this would result in a more compact (and less bug-prone) code.

Comment: @AnupamKhulbe Maybe i got you wrong, i thought the site (and content/DOM) is generated via JS. So creating unique id's would have seemed quite easy. And you could factory the eventlisteners. Code should be relatively clean then. Altough it's still a messy solution anyway. But the whole web is ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something like this built into the browser. However, you may use something like this (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```js
$( "#didichange_tbl" ).delegate( "input", "change", function() {
  console.log("table has changed!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table id="didichange_tbl">
        <tr>
          <td><input/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input/></td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Something like this would work, but I'd need to do this at the individual table cells. Doing this at the table level will not allow me to identify which specific cells were updated. Also, with this approach, I'd need to assign a unique id to each table cell and then store that id (in sessionStorage, for example) to indicate that it was updated. This quickly becomes a complicated solution, although it's technically feasible.

Comment: @11AND2 my suggestion would be using on instead of delegate. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904904/delegate-vs-on-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few solutions, the best thing I've found was written by [conradgray](https://coderwall.com/conradgray) on the coderwall.com blog: https://coderwall.com/p/lxl3zw. I decided to add the articles contents to a post, in case at some time the original doesn't exist anymore.

This is his solution:

```js
var editable = document.getElementById('text');
editable.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log('Hey, somebody changed something in my text!');
});
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at arcu ac dui eleifend suscipit a ut est. Ut iaculis ut massa non accumsan. Quisque hendrerit nisl at egestas cursus.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set `contenteditable` only to leaf elements and text nodes and then listen for `input` event. That way you can extract the exact source of the event.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  console.log(event.target);
});

function addContentEditable(el) {
  if (el.children.length === 0) { el.setAttribute('contenteditable', true) }
  if (el.nodeType === 3) { el.setAttribute('contenteditable', true) }
  [...el.children].forEach(c => {
    addContentEditable(c);
  });
}

addContentEditable(document.body);
```

```html
<div class="pad">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some more text<a> and a link</a></p>
  <p>Even <b>more</b> text</p>
</div>
```