# on and bind not working but delegate works

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know why in my code "delegate" function works but not "on" or "bind"?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/UPNaF/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("p","click",function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","pink");
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("click","p",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","pink"); // this will change color on inside p
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UPNaF/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("click","p",function(){
    $('p').css("background-color","pink"); // this will change color on all p
  });
});
```

"As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method."

"As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers."

- Using the `.bind()` method is very costly as it attaches the same
     event handler to  every item matched in your selector.

  You should stop using the `.live()` method as it is deprecated and has
     a  lot of problems with it.

  The `.delegate()` method gives a lot of "bang for your buck" when 
     dealing with performance and reacting to dynamically added elements.

  That the new .on() method is mostly syntax sugar that can mimic
     `.bind()`, `.live()`,  or   `.delegate()` depending on how you call it.

  The new direction is to use the new `.on` method. Get familiar with
     the  syntax and start using it on all your jQuery 1.7+ projects.

[Reference](http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so we can use either of them (delegate, on ,bind and live?) for event delegation; are there any technical differences between them for event delegation?

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently using is applicable for **[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** . The correct parameters order for **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** is:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

so you need to specify the event first then follow by your selector:

```
$("div").on("click","p",function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","pink");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UPNaF/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so we can use either of them (delegate, on ,bind and live?) for event delegation; are there any technical differences between them for event delegation?

Comment: You can check here mate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on

Answer (score 0):

`Event type` must be first parameter in `.on()` statement

`selector` must be second parameter.

`data` must be third parameter and its optional

Instead of

```
 $("div").on("p","click",function(){ 
       $("p").css("background-color","pink");
 });
```

use

```
 $("div").on("click","p",function(){ 
      $("p").css("background-color","pink");
 });
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/UPNaF/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so we can use either of them (delegate, on ,bind and live?) for event delegation; are there any technical differences between them for event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('div').on('click','p',function...` use `$('div p').on('click',function...`

http://jsfiddle.net/UPNaF/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div p").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","pink");
  });
});
```