# Jquery - Delegate multiple element and multiple event

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

Im just ask my question fast.(because my english is not so good)

Can i use delegate like this or other similar way?

```
$( 'body ').delegate({
    'input[type=text]': {
        'change': function( e ) {
            //codes..
        },
        'blur': function( e ) {
            //codes..
        }
    },
    '.ipsum': {
        'click': function( e ) {
            //codes..
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? If you are using jQuery 1.7 or above then use `.on()` instead `.delegate()`.

More information about this can be found at [.delegate() vs .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on)

To go back at your example:

The best way would be to split the 2 elements like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').on({
    change: function() {
        // code
    },
    blur: function() {
        // code
    }
});
```

Second element:

```
$('.ipsum').on({
    click: function() {
        // code
    }
});
```

Comment: Im using 1.11.1 and i know the on() function. on() not work like delegate(). I perferred to use delegate() but i connot do it my way :/

Comment: what is the reason you want to combine the elements and events in one delegate?

Comment: Tell me, which one is better. Using delegate for 5 elements(has 2 or 3 event) separately or using 1 delegate for 5 elements? .. For example > delegate for .one, delegate for .two, delegate for .three, delegate for .four, delegate for .five ||or|| delegate for (.one,.two,.three,.four,.five) wich one is better logic?

Comment: do they have the same logic for each of these elements?