# jQuery On Is Not Working

Tags: jquery

In the following js file, first `on` click event is not working but the second is working. Then I thought to use `delegate()` here but I don't think `delegate()` will solve my problem because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on). Can anybody tell me the reason why the first `on` click event is not triggering. Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#job_category_chosen').on('click', '.search-choice-close', function(){
            console.log('This is not working.');
        });

        jQuery(document).on('click', '#job_category_chosen .chosen-results', function(){
            console.log('This is working.');
        });
    });
```

Here is my HTML form...

```
<form action="/submit-job-form/" method="post" id="submit-job-form" class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Your account</label>
        <div class="field account-sign-in">
            You are currently signed in as aviator.
            <a class="button" href="http://local.wordpress-trunk.dev/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.wordpress-trunk.dev%2Fsubmit-job-form%2F&amp;_wpnonce=81838608ef">Sign out</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Job Information Fields -->

    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_title">
        <label for="job_title">Title</label>
        <div class="field required-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="job_title" id="job_title" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="" required="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_location">
        <label for="job_location">Location <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="job_location" id="job_location" placeholder="e.g. &quot;London&quot;" value="" maxlength="">
            <small class="description">Leave this blank if the location is not important</small> </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_region">
        <label for="job_region">Listing Region</label>
        <div class="field required-field">
            <select name="job_region" id="job_region" class="postform">
                <option class="level-0" value="13">Maharashtra</option>
                <option class="level-1" value="12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pune</option>
                <option class="level-1" value="14">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thane</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="15">New Delhi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-application">
        <label for="application">Contact email/URL</label>
        <div class="field required-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="application" id="application" placeholder="Enter an email address or website URL" value="pandurang.agjal@wisdmlabs.com" maxlength="" required="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_category">
        <label for="job_category">Listing Category</label>
        <div class="field required-field">
            <select name="job_category[]" id="job_category" class="job-manager-category-dropdown " multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose a category…" data-no_results_text="No results match" data-multiple_text="Select Some Options" style="display: none;">
                <option class="level-0" value="17">HR</option>
                <option class="level-1" value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Development</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="16">Sales</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="18">Service</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="19">test</option>
            </select>
            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 176px;" title="" id="job_category_chosen">
                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                    <li class="search-choice"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Development</span>
                        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="search-choice"><span>Sales</span>
                        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="2"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="search-choice"><span>HR</span>
                        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="search-field">
                        <input type="text" value="Choose a category…" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="chosen-drop">
                    <ul class="chosen-results">
                        <li class="result-selected level-0" style="" data-option-array-index="0">HR</li>
                        <li class="result-selected level-1" style="" data-option-array-index="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Development</li>
                        <li class="result-selected level-0" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Sales</li>
                        <li class="active-result level-0" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Service</li>
                        <li class="active-result level-0" style="" data-option-array-index="4">test</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_hours">
        <label for="job_hours">Hours of Operation <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="40%">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th align="left">Open</th>
                        <th align="left">Close</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Monday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[1][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[1][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Tuesday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[2][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[2][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Wednesday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[3][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[3][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Thursday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[4][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[4][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Friday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[5][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[5][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Saturday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[6][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[6][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Sunday</td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[0][start]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="business-hour">
                            <input type="text" class="timepicker ui-timepicker-input" name="job_hours[0][end]" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-featured_image">
        <label for="featured_image">Cover Image <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <div class="job-manager-uploaded-files">
            </div>

            <input type="file" class="input-text wp-job-manager-file-upload" data-file_types="jpg|jpeg|gif|png" name="featured_image" id="featured_image" placeholder="">
            <small class="description">
            Maximum file size: 1 GB.    </small> </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-gallery_images">
        <label for="gallery_images">Gallery Images <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <div class="job-manager-uploaded-files">
            </div>

            <input type="file" class="input-text wp-job-manager-file-upload" data-file_types="jpg|jpeg|gif|png" multiple="" name="gallery_images[]" id="gallery_images" placeholder="">
            <small class="description">
            Maximum file size: 1 GB.    </small> </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-job_description">
        <label for="job_description">Description</label>
        <div class="field required-field">
            <div id="wp-job_description-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active">
                <link rel="stylesheet" id="editor-buttons-css" href="http://local.wordpress-trunk.dev/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
                <div id="wp-job_description-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container">
                    <div id="mceu_8" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="application" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px;">
                        <div id="mceu_8-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout">
                            <div id="mceu_9" class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group">
                                <div id="mceu_9-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout">
                                    <div id="mceu_10" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-first mce-last" role="toolbar">
                                        <div id="mceu_10-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                                            <div id="mceu_11" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                                <div id="mceu_11-body">
                                                    <div id="mceu_0" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_0" role="button" aria-label="Bold">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bold"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="mceu_1" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_1" role="button" aria-label="Italic">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-italic"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="mceu_12" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                                <div id="mceu_12-body">
                                                    <div id="mceu_2" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_2" role="button" aria-label="Bullet list">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bullist"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="mceu_3" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_3" role="button" aria-label="Numbered list">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-numlist"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="mceu_13" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                                <div id="mceu_13-body">
                                                    <div id="mceu_4" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_4" role="button" aria-label="Insert/edit link">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-link"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="mceu_5" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_5" role="button" aria-label="Remove link">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-unlink"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="mceu_14" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                                <div id="mceu_14-body">
                                                    <div id="mceu_6" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first mce-disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_6" role="button" aria-label="Undo" aria-disabled="true">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-undo"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="mceu_7" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last mce-disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_7" role="button" aria-label="Redo" aria-disabled="true">
                                                        <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-redo"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mceu_15" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;">
                                <iframe id="job_description_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press Alt-Shift-H for help" src='javascript:""' style="width: 100%; height: 172px; display: block;" data-gramm_id="4dc30845-5a2d-be30-1d8f-baeb161accb0"
                                data-gramm="true" gramm-ifr="true"></iframe>
                                <grammarly-btn>
                                    <div style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 2;" class="_9b5ef6-textarea_btn _9b5ef6-not_focused" data-grammarly-reactid=".0">
                                        <div class="_9b5ef6-transform_wrap" data-grammarly-reactid=".0.0">
                                            <div title="Protected by Grammarly" class="_9b5ef6-status" data-grammarly-reactid=".0.0.0">&nbsp;</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </grammarly-btn>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mceu_16" class="mce-statusbar mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;">
                                <div id="mceu_16-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                                    <div id="mceu_17" class="mce-path mce-flow-layout-item mce-first">
                                        <div role="button" class="mce-path-item mce-last" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_17-0" aria-level="0">p</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="mceu_18" class="mce-flow-layout-item mce-last mce-resizehandle"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-resize"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="8" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="job_description" id="job_description" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="wdmjm-sjf-main-div-ques">
        <fieldset class="">hi26</fieldset>
        <fieldset class="">hi27</fieldset>
        <fieldset class="">hi34</fieldset>
    </div>

    <!-- Company Information Fields -->
    <h2>Company Details</h2>


    <fieldset class="fieldset-company_website">
        <label for="company_website">Website <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="company_website" id="company_website" placeholder="http://" value="wisdmlabs.com" maxlength="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-phone">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-company_video">
        <label for="company_video">Video <small>(optional)</small></label>
        <div class="field ">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="company_video" id="company_video" placeholder="A link to a video about your company" value="" maxlength="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="job_manager_form" value="submit-job">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="0">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_job" class="button" value="Preview">
    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: The probable answer, is that `#job_category_chosen` is a dynamic element inserted later, and you don't understand how delegation works.

Comment: I tried `'body'` and `document` too instead of `'#job_category_chosen'`...

Comment: Is `#job_category_chosen` parent of `.search-choice-close`? It needs to be.

Comment: Yeah, `#job_category_chosen` is parent of `.search-choice-close`. That's why it is working...

Comment: It's not necessary to post THAT much HTML code, just the code that really is needed. Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with `bind()` or `live()`. As this are alternate options for you.

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for a while

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because your `a` element doesn't contain any content, so you can't really click it.

Try putting it like this:

```
<li class="search-choice"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Development</span>
     <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1">SOME TEXT</a>
</li>
```

And then click on that text.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w579v4v8/)

EDIT:

So you either put your text inside of your `a` element, or make handler for your `span` or whole `li`.

```
$('#job_category_chosen').on('click', '.search-choice span', function(){
      alert('This is working.');
});
```