# JQUERY / JS / HTML - Scroll to div not working on JQuery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

i've just **changed my Jquery version to 3.1.1** and all of sudden some of my **scripts stopped working**.

I've already worked out most of them but still cannot resolve the issue with the **scroll to anchor script**...

**Here it is:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

It just won't work now, any idea how to work it out?

Here's the **html script** part too:

```
<a class="scrolltomain" href="#content-wrapper">
<span>
<img id="scroller" src="img/scrolldown-1.gif"></img>
<center>Kliknij<br>lub<br>przewiń</center>
</span>
</a>
```

Would be really grateful if someone could help me.

BTW, chrome console wouldn't show any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no such tag as `</img>`. Image tags are self closing, a la: `<img src=" " />`

And you need to define the location *before* the animation. Simply define a variable before the `animate()`function and then call the variable within the function.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisRef = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( thisRef ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
a { display: block; text-align: center;  height: 400px; }
#content-wrapper { background: red; height: 300px; margin-top: 500px; color: #fff; font-size: 2em; line-height: 1.6; text-align:center; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="scrolltomain" href="#content-wrapper"><img id="scroller" src="http://placekitten.com/25/25" /><br />Kliknij<br />lub<br />przewiń</a>
<div id="content-wrapper"> Content </div>
```

Comment: Actually my script started working after your advice, but i'm still not fully happy with the way it works :P Instead of animating the scroll it just 'jumps' to the div, have tried working it out but still no clue what else am I doing wrong

Comment: Scott's answer was of much help, in fact it works flawlessly. The problem i had with the animation itself was the `overflow-x: hidden;` style anchored to `body`. It's working perfect now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try .delegate() instead of .on().... .on() is new to Jquery 1.7 so if you went backwards then you'll need to use delegate or live.

[.delegate() vs .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359085/delegate-vs-on)